# Excel functions: indirect address column

Tags: excel

First time asking a question after reading a lot in the past.

I'm running the following array function excel:

```
INDEX('Available Options'!$A$1:$CM$137,$B$1,
SMALL(
IF(
INDIRECT("'Feasibility Options'!"&ADDRESS($B$1,COLUMN('Feasibility Options'!$G$1),1,1)&":"&ADDRESS($B$1,COLUMN('Feasibility Options'!$O$1),1,1))=2,
COLUMN(INDIRECT("'Feasibility Options'!"&ADDRESS($B$1,COLUMN('Feasibility Options'!$G$1),1,1)&":"&ADDRESS($B$1,COLUMN('Feasibility Options'!$O$1),1,1)))),
ROW('Available Options'!1:1)))
```

The idea behind this is that there are a number of cells which either have 1s, 2s or 3s in (1 means default, 2 means an alternative and 3 means inactive) in a separate tab called 'Feasibility Options', and the prices for these options are held in the 'Available Options' tab. $B$1 contains a row number produced through a separate calculation.

Evaluating this formula gives a value error when resolving the Indirect part of the function, but the function works if I replace the column number formulae with column numbers as below:

```
INDEX('Available Options'!$A$1:$CM$137,$B$1,
SMALL(
IF(INDIRECT("'Feasibility Options'!"&ADDRESS($B$1,7,1,1)&":"&ADDRESS($B$1,15,1,1))=2,COLUMN(INDIRECT("'Feasibility Options'!"&ADDRESS($B$1,7,1,1)&":"&ADDRESS($B$1,15,1,1)))),ROW('Available Options'!1:1)))
```

Could someone explain why this would happen and how to fix it? I ideally need to use cell references rather than hardcoded column numbers as I will likely need to add more columns in at a later date.

Thanks for any help you can give and apologies if I've missed a previous thread which answers this sort of question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but I suspect the problem is caused by the `COLUMN` function which returns an array (even for a single value) and sometimes Excel has trouble processing this:

You can normally make it work by wrapping `COLUMN` in a `SUM` or `MAX` function, e.g.

`MAX(COLUMN('Feasibility Options'!$G$1))`

or using `COLUMNS` function instead, something like

`COLUMNS('Feasibility Options'!$G$1:G1)`

which can be dragged to increment

Better still would be to replace the whole `INDIRECT/ADDRESS` parts with `INDEX`, which should be simpler, shorter and more efficient. I can give you more detail on that if you're interested

Comment: Thanks, the MAX function around the COLUMN function worked. How would the Index function replace the INDIRECT/ADDRESS functions? I've not used INDEX functions much before.

Comment: You should be able to replace all of this part - `INDIRECT("'Feasibility Options'!"&ADDRESS($B$1,COLUMN('Feasibility Options'!$G$1),1,1)&":"&ADDRESS($B$1,COLUMN('Feasibility Options'!$O$1),1,1))` with just `=INDEX('Feasibility Options'!$G$1:$O$200,$B$1,0))` - replace the `200` in the latter with the highest possible value for $B$1

Comment: Thanks, that's worked too, but when I drag down the formula (to take the second, third, etc. smallest value, based on the row function at the end of the formula) it gives the following error message:
You cannot change part of an array.